# Finding convergence (or divergence) of $\int_0^{1/e} \frac{dx}{x \ln^2 x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> Compute or prove the divergence of $$\int_0^{1/e}  \frac{dx}{x \ln^2 x}$$

I have tried to find the usual derivative  taking integration from α..(0<α<1/e)to 1/e..it turned out be log0..but the given solution is 1.

Comment: Please use MathJax in future. It is a type of $\LaTeX$. A tutorial on it from this site is readily available online.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\frac1e}\dfrac{1}{x\ln^2x}\ dx$$

Use u-substitution: $u=\ln x\implies du=\dfrac{dx}{x}$

first compute without boundaries
$$=\int\dfrac{1}{u^2}\ du=\dfrac{u^{-2+1}}{-2+1}=-\left[\dfrac{1}{\ln x}\right]_0^{\frac1e}=1$$

Comment: Pardon me if this is a very stupid question, but wouldn't the integral diverge because of the fact that $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{x\log^2x}=+\infty$$

Comment: @clathratus Yes, it diverges because it has discontinuity at $x=0$ which gives improper bound

Comment: So why does your answer say that $$\int_0^{\frac1e}\frac{dx}{x\log^2x}=1$$

Comment: @clathratus I am evaluating the limit for $\dfrac{1}{\ln x}$ but not for $\dfrac{1}{x\ln^2x}$

Comment: Your answer to the first comment is not correct. The question in the comment is: doesn't the integral diverge since the integrand blows up at $0$? Answer: No

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Substitute $u = \ln x$ with $du = dx/x$ to get $\int u^{-2}du$...